# Ruby on Rails: delayed jobs are not working with mailer and give route error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, mailer

I try to implement delayed_job for my mailer and have some problems even follow the documentation.

application.rb

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module AjaxApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.1
    config.action_view.embed_authenticity_token_in_remote_forms = true
    config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job
    
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
  end
end
```

I have also config/initilizers/delayed_jobs.rb

```
Delayed::Worker.max_attempts = 5 #25
Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = false
Delayed::Worker.sleep_delay = 60
Delayed::Worker.max_run_time = 5.minutes
Delayed::Worker.read_ahead = 10
Delayed::Worker.default_queue_name = 'default'
Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = !Rails.env.test?
Delayed::Worker.raise_signal_exceptions = :term
Delayed::Worker.logger = Logger.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'log', 'delayed_job.log'))
```

and migration as well

```
class CreateDelayedJobs < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def self.up
    create_table :delayed_jobs do |table|
      table.integer :priority, default: 0, null: false # Allows some jobs to jump to the front of the queue
      table.integer :attempts, default: 0, null: false # Provides for retries, but still fail eventually.
      table.text :handler,                 null: false # YAML-encoded string of the object that will do work
      table.text :last_error                           # reason for last failure (See Note below)
      table.datetime :run_at                           # When to run. Could be Time.zone.now for immediately, or sometime in the future.
      table.datetime :locked_at                        # Set when a client is working on this object
      table.datetime :failed_at                        # Set when all retries have failed (actually, by default, the record is deleted instead)
      table.string :locked_by                          # Who is working on this object (if locked)
      table.string :queue                              # The name of the queue this job is in
      table.timestamps null: true
    end

    add_index :delayed_jobs, [:priority, :run_at], name: "delayed_jobs_priority"
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :delayed_jobs
  end
end
```

And I run my worker as well by command `rails jobs:work`

After all this setup I try to send password reset email

My password_resets_controller.rb

```
 def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:password_reset][:email].downcase)
    if @user
      @user.create_reset_digest
      @user.send_password_reset_email
      flash[:info] = 'Email sent with password reset instructions.'
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Email address not found.'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

It’s called method from user.rb

```
def send_password_reset_email
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver_later
#deliver_later must working under the hood of delayed_job
end
```

I also tried

```
def send_password_reset_email
    UserMailer.delay.password_reset(self)
end
```

and

```
def send_password_reset_email
    UserMailer.password_reset(self)
end
handle_asynchronously :send_password_reset_email
```

In all cases I got errors appearing by the http://localhost:3000/delayed_job/failed?queues=mailers  (yes, I use gem 'delayed_job_web')

```
ID 1
Priority 0
Attempts 1
Queue mailers
Handler
--- !ruby/object:ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::DelayedJobAdapter::JobWrapper
job_data:
  job_class: ActionMailer::DeliveryJob
  job_id: f5efa6e2-18e5-4d99-836b-8800d34b7289
  provider_job_id: 
  queue_name: mailers
  priority: 
  arguments:
  - UserMailer
  - password_reset
  - deliver_now
  - _aj_globalid: gid://ajax-app/User/1
  executions: 0
  exception_executions: {}
  locale: en
  timezone: UTC
  enqueued_at: '2021-10-31T17:49:54Z'
Last Error No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"password_resets", :email=>"psychotrop@gmail.com", :...
```

But I have in routes.rb

```
resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
```

When I am using mailer without delayed_job everything works as expected.
Pls help to fix that issue. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "psychotrop@gmail.com"

  #def welcome_email(user)
  #  @user = user
  #  @url  = 'http://example.com/login'
  #  mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome to Test Site')
  #end

  def registration_confirmation(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Verify your accounts')
    end
  #handle_asynchronously :registration_confirmation

    def account_activation(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: user.email, subject: "Account activation", template_name: 'account_activation'
  end
  #handle_asynchronously :account_activation

  def password_reset(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: user.email, subject: "Password reset", template_name: 'password_reset'
  end
  #handle_asynchronously :password_reset
  
end
```

password_reset.html.erb

```
<h1>Password reset</h1>

<p>To reset your password click the link below:</p>

<%= link_to "Reset password", edit_password_reset_url(@user.reset_token,
                                                      email: @user.email) %>

<p>This link will expire in two hours.</p>

<p>
If you did not request your password to be reset, please ignore this email and
your password will stay as it is.
</p>
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
rake routes | grep password_reset

password_resets POST     /password_resets(.:format)                                                               password_resets#create
                   new_password_reset GET      /password_resets/new(.:format)                                                           password_resets#new
                  edit_password_reset GET      /password_resets/:id/edit(.:format)                                                      password_resets#edit
                       password_reset PATCH    /password_resets/:id(.:format)                                                           password_resets#update
                                      PUT      /password_resets/:id(.:format)                                                           password_resets#update
```

Comment: seems the error is coming from UserMailer's method or email template. Can you please edit your question with UserMailer code and email template.

Comment: @NitinSrivastava. Thank you for response. I added mailer and template

Comment: seems problem is in the `edit_password_reset_url(@user.reset_token, email: @user.email)` url in the `password_reset.html.erb` template. To check the right url, please run `rake routes | grep password_reset` on your terminal and update the question with the command result. We are close to fix this.

Comment: @NitinSrivastava Thank you that are still here, I edited my post. Seems like url is fine

Answer (score 2):

From the routes, the `edit_password_reset` url needs a resource id. You can fix it by passing the `@user` as param of the url.

```
<%= link_to "Reset password", edit_password_reset_url(@user) %>
```

If you want to send additional params then

```
<%= link_to "Reset password", edit_password_reset_url(@user, reset_token: @user.reset_token, email: @user.email) %>
```

If you want to use `reset_password_token` rather than `:id` in your url then use customize routes, like

**In routes.rb**

```
resources :password_resets, only: [:new, :create, :update] # Take out edit route

get '/password_resets/:reset_password_token/edit', to: "password_resets#edit", as: "edit_password_reset"
```

Now in email template

```
<%= link_to "Reset password", edit_password_reset_url(@user.reset_token) %>
```

Let me know if you find this helpful.